# Characters in text editor are overlapping each other

Tags: interface

I am using blender 2.8, and started using Python scripting recently. But characters in the text editor are overlapping each other, and it is hard to see them. Just like this:
[image: characters are overlapping each other]
I looked preference settings but found nothing, settings in Themes>Text Style do not affect them.
Did anyone encounter this problem before? Or have idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a custom font? Check it in Edit>Preferences>Interface>Text Rendering.